# Request Spec failing on Association - Rails 5 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I've got a request spec failing on a model with an association; when I `binding.pry` into it I can manually create the record with the same parameters, but when I pass them through the `post '/path/model'` request, it fails and says the association should exist.  That's good - I want the association to be required.  But the `post` action seems to be unable to pass.

```
# job model
belongs_to :worker
validates :title, presence: true

# worker model
has_many :jobs

# jobs controller
# POST /jobs
def create
  @job = Job.create!(job_params)
  json_response(@job, :created)
end

# jobs request spec
describe "POST /v1/jobs" do
  context "when the request is valid" do
    before {
      post '/v1/jobs', params: {
        title: "Whatever",
        worker_id: Worker.first.id,
      }
    }

    it "creates a job" do
      puts request.body.read 
      puts response.body
      expect(json["title"]).to eq("Whatever")
    end

    it "returns status code 201" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
    end
  end
end
```

These tests both fail.  The result of the `puts` statements above is:

```
title=Whatever&worker_id=21
{"message":"Validation failed: Worker must exist"}
```

If I put a `binding.pry` there instead, the following successfully creates a `Job`:

```
Job.create(title: "Whatever", worker_id: Worker.first.id)
```

My migrations are:

```
# jobs migration
create_table :jobs do |t|
  t.references :worker, index: true
  t.text :title
end

# worker migration
create_table :workers do |t|
  t.text :first_name
  ...
end
```

What am I missing here?  I know that the `belongs_to` association is now non-optional in Rails 5, but again, **I want that**.  So I don't want to flag it `optional` just to get my tests to pass.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you allowing `worker_id` in your `job_params`?

Comment: @jemminger yeah, that was the trick. Posted the answer below, but SO tells me I have to wait two days to accept it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: if @jemminger helped you finding the solution to the problem, you could reward him the question, he could update it with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a problem in the controller; I'm using strict parameters and didn't have the `worker_id` in the list of permitted params.  Easy to overlook but it's a trap!  Hope this helps someone else, especially since all the advice about the `belongs_to` association for Rails 5 says, "just make it optional."

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't created a `Worker` for the spec to work with. Remember that your database is empty in each spec, so `Worker.first.id` will fail, because there is no workers in the database.

In your spec you want to create a worker (I use FactoryBot, the same concept applies to fixtures or whatever you're using):

```
context "when the request is valid" do
  let!(:worker) { create :worker }
  before {
    post '/v1/jobs', params: {
      title: "Whatever",
      worker_id: worker.id,
    }
  }

  it "creates a job" do
    puts request.body.read 
    puts response.body
    expect(json["title"]).to eq("Whatever")
  end

  it "returns status code 201" do
    expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
  end
end
```

I used `let!` because that will force the record to be created before the spec is run. Now `Worker.first.id` will find that worker, and you're on your way!

Comment: Yeah, I'm using FactoryBot as well.  So - I will try this, buuuuut wouldn't the `request.body.read` showing `worker_id=21` indicate that there *is* a worker in the DB (as called by `Worker.first.id` in the params)?  Does this association mean I can assign the Job to an existing Worker or I have to create a new one every time?  (workers are getting created by FactoryBot elsewhere, I believe)

Comment: As a follow up, I tried your adjustments, and got the same output messages: `title=Whatever&worker_id=21` and `{"message":"Validation failed: Worker must exist"}` (which is weird because I would have thought the id would be different, though that assumes the db is created the same every time which I know it's not)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that it's caused by `belongs_to` associations being required by default in Rails 5.

What I usually do is make it optional for creates:  `belongs_to :worker, optional: :new_record?` and then write a test to ensure that it did get created.

Comment: You mean, make the association optional and test that it got created anyway?  Hmmmm.  Ultimately, we don't want a job to get created without a worker; the UI should also enforce this but isn't that the point of validations?